# How can I display vue.js data in blade

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I am doing a small project with vue.js and laravel. I have a list of products, when I click on a specific product on "Quick view" button I want to show all data about that product in a modal but the data is not showing in the modal.

Can you help me please. Here is my code:

```html
@extends('app')

@section('content')
    <div id ="crud" class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">Lista de Articulo</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="wrap-icon right-section col-md-12" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#list" >
            <div class="wrap-icon-section wishlist">
                <a href="#" class="link-direction">
                    <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <div class="left-info">
                        <span class="index">0 item</span>
                        <br>
                        <span class="title">Wishlist</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div v-for="keep in keeps" class="col-md-4" style="width:25%;" @mouseover="showByIndex = keep" @mouseout="showByIndex = null">
                <div class="container">
                    <img :src="keep.foto" style="width:100%; max-width:150px;">
                    <button class="btn" v-show="showByIndex === keep" v-on:click.prevent="showKeep(keep)">Quick view</button>
                </div>
                <h3>
                    <b> @{{keep.nombre}}</b>
                </h3>
                <p> @{{keep.descripcion}}</p>
```

Comment: You will need to create vue components and then register them and use components tag in blade template.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. The error was because I called the modal file outside the div. Thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 0):

you can't send data directly from vue in blade structure, you need to write a component for that.

https://v3.vuejs.org/examples/modal.html#modal-component